# Android java SMS Service

Tags: java, android, sms, service

Есть приложение для отправки *SMS*, для него необходим *Service*, который будет это делать, использовал для написания кода ресурс:

http://www.mobilab.ru/androiddev/smsandroid.html

Там всё грамотно написано, но там пример не для сервиса, кто может помочь? Очень прошу

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы за Вас здесь написали потенциально опасное ПО?

Comment: @Kaminsky вы не правы. Это абсолютно нормальное ПО и более того стандартное я бы сказал. ТС хочет отправку СМС возложить на `Service`, что в общем то справедливо. Так что не поддержу минусование равно как и "тревогу".

Comment: С другой стороны, меня так и тянет поставить минус за «срочно!!!».

Comment: У меня нету цели создать ПО с рассылкой на короткие номера, просто сама суть приложения нуждается через отправку СМС сервисом

Comment: @VladD у меня тоже тянулась рука :)

Answer (score 1):

Кусочек кода:

```
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

Надо возложить на `IntentService` - как его запускать - Гугл в помощь.

Comment: Про IntentService слышал,попробую,спасибо, но есть ещё одна беда,данный сервис должен запускаться при запуске приложения,в принципе BroadcastReceiver тут мне поможет, но данный сервис должен сам определять,когда надо отправить сообщение, из UI вызывать сервис не надо, нужно чтобы сервис сам занимался этим вопросом, т.к. отправка смс должна будет осуществляться постоянно без включенного приложения, прошу вас мне помочь ибо сам ещё зелёный. Если вас не затруднит, то можно будет с вами поговорить в скайпе или хотя бы по мылу?

Comment: @BORSHEVIK не надо со мной связываться. Тема недавно уже [обсуждалась](http://hashcode.ru/questions/332766/java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-broadcastreceiver-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-activity) - просто почитайте.

Comment: Спасибо,конечно, но использовать BroadcastReceiver я умею,не в этом была проблема. У меня есть БД,которая используется и главным поток с UI и потоком Service, и когда они берут из неё данные одновременно, то система падает и сервис перезагружается,а это не то,что мне хотелось сделать. Главный поток обновляет БД, а сервис периодически его проверяет и отправляет СМС, и чистит частично БД и главный кастыль в том,что они синхронно не могут подключаться к БД и редактироват её,а как реализовать так,чтобы пока 1 читает БД, другой её чтобы не читал,пока не знаю, остаётся вводить глобальные переменные

Comment: @BORSHEVIK Сформулируйте как новый вопрос - с чувством толком и расстановкой. Постараемся помочь.

Comment: Хорошо,попробую описать суть правильно

Comment: Вот ссылка на сформулированный вопрос

http://hashcode.ru/questions/334680/android-java-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-service-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%B4-sqlite